# Use xbindkeys & xdotool to bind mouse buttons

Tags: mouse-pointer

I am very new on **Ubuntu desktop** and just like it so much. Now i get a problem. My OS is **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**.

I am a designer. I use a lot of middle click when i do 3d drawings. (A lot of my mouse's middle licks have been dead already). I want to bind button 8 & 9 to middle click.

By the way, I found another function can exchange button:

`xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 9 3 4 5 6 7 8 2`

But I still want more button 2. So I tried xbindkeys & xdotool
I try to follow the webside: 
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/11/how-to-bind-mouse-buttons-to-keyboard.html

what I add in ".xbindkeysrc" file is:

```
"xdotool key 'z'"
    b:8

"xdotool click '2'"
    b:9
```

Or

```
"xdotool click 2"
    b:9
```

**Now my problem is Button 8 works well. (can use as z) My button 9 doesn't work.**

And I have try command in terminal:

```
xdotool click 2
xdotool mousedown 2
```

it works well.

Anybody can help me on this? Thanks a lot. But my English is poor, use simple English please.

Comment: Oh hi. My one is Ubuntu desktop

Comment: Thanks. I am very new of this.

Comment: Make and model of mouse?

Comment: I use Blender to do 3D drawing. A lot of drawings. Not model of mouse.

Comment: If the buttons are on the mouse, what is the make and model of mouse?

Comment: Sorry. My English is poor. You ask me what kind of mouse i use, is it? My mouse is https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51JbAlb0suL._AC_SY355_.jpg

Comment: The make and model of the mouse, not a picture.